# Hall-sensor BLDC motor control

Tags: motor, stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, stm32f0

I have a BLDC motor with Hall-sensors installed. (using ST's FOC lib, with Hall sensors)  When I start the motor, it has very bad sound, but it starts and has very low torque. What parameters should I tune?

Here is a screenshot of the Hall-sensor settings: 
[image: Hall sensor parameters]

What is "Placement electrical angle"? Is it the angle between the Hall-sensors and the coils?

For me, the FOC lib does not seem to change the speed of the motor on order. Should it work anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be blindly tweaking parameters without actually understanding what goes on underneath.  The best way to guarantee that is to write the motor driver code yourself.  That will probably be easier than vetting someone else's.  Also, that forces understanding of the principles and the code.  Without both, you'll just be forever poking around in the dark.

Even if you eventually get something that appears to work, you have no way of knowing if it works optimally, and under what conditions it might fail.  At this level, there is no substitute for actually understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have the correct sequence of the windings. There are three windings, each having two connecting wires. Usually the are connected in star configuration, so you get three wires out of it.

The second thing is to know the electrical angle. If the magnet has two poles, then electrical angle is equal to the mechanical angle of rotation, you have each winding displaced by 120 degrees. $$\varphi_{electric}=\dfrac{\varphi_{mechanical}}{N_{polepairs}}$$

One pole pair is North and South (NS), it is the minimal pole pair number, the machine is so called two pole. Four pole machine means, two pole pairs NSNS. In such case the electrical angle for one revolution is 180 degrees, and displacement is 60 degrees.

I think you should read carefully the application note and insert the correct numbers.

EDIT:

Just guessing, the placement electrical angle is just an offset between rotor flux and the  transducer flux in terms of an electrical angle. If the Hall sensors are mounted directly in the stator, then this is 0. If you have an add-on magnet with Hall sensors - Hall encoder, then there could be an offset present.